# Multi-dimensional analysis in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, pentaho, olap, business-intelligence, mondrian

I was wondering is there any way of doing multi-dimensional analysis in MongoDB? Besides using  a middle SQL like layer to stage the data between MongoDB and the analysis engine.

I am trying to use a Pentaho with MongoDB for BI, but I worry about how to handle Multi-dimensional analysis or even if I should try to do it at all. I know that there were some plans for Mondrian to access directly mongodb but nothing has been implemented yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Pentaho EE 5.1 due out sometime this half of the year analyzer will have native mongo support - but that is only EE.

Your other option is indeed to use a SQL layer, and optiq is a good choice for that. The Saiku guys have got mondrian running via optiq to Mongo - and have even built support for aggregations.  Note: The native Pentaho support mentioned above does NOT use optiq.

Unfortunately there's few other options at this stage!

Comment: Can you elaborate about the advantages of using optiq over other possible layers, like for example Hadoop.

Comment: Hadoop? as a sql layer for analytics? something like impala? I'd still question if that would perform well enough. How many rows are in mongo? Would an analytic db be better, e.g. monetdb or vectorwise?  One big advantage of optiq is that the lead developer is the mondrian founder, so you can be sure they will play well together!

Comment: My bad, I meant something like Hadoop with Hive or Impala, since I am pretty sure that should work though probably the performance wouldn't be good. Still optiq lead developer being the mondrian founder is good news, what I wanted to know is how it is performance wise in this situation compared with other solutions since I did a quick google search and didn't find much info about that.

Comment: I can't be sure as haven't tried it directly but suspect it will be pretty slow.  Try mocking something up to test each variation..

Comment: Hi Codek I tried optiq mongo for saiku but it didn't work. Can you have any tutorial or link which explain how optiq-mongo-saiku work together.

Answer (score 1):

how about your data type? If they are structured data and you want have SQL and OLAP capability, you could refer to Kylin OLAP which just open sourced this month: http://kylin.io/

Disclosure:I'm team member of this open source project